# IOS style Emoji keyboard in android

Tags: android, emoji

I want to send emoticons from android to iPhone , i developed emoticon keyboard as shown in this [link](https://github.com/chiragjain/Emoticons-Keyboard) ,Whenever an emoticon is selected  , i am sending corresponding Unicode of particular emoticon to iPhone , iPhone converts received Unicode to its corresponding Emoticon. In order to achieve this i have created map of drawable to its corresponding Unicode , like This

```
public static HashMap<Integer, String> unicode = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

static
{

//for sending
unicode.put(R.drawable.emoji01, "\\uD83D\\uDE04");//Smiling Face with Open Mouth and Smiling Eyes
unicode.put(R.drawable.emoji02, "\\uD83D\\uDE03");//Smiling Face with Open Mouth
}
```

So whenever an emoticon is selected, i send Unicode to iPhone using above hashmap,
This approach works fine but for this, i have to create manual mapping of all such emoticons . There  are almost 844 emoticons. So my question is, am i doing it in a correct way? or is there a better option than creating manual mapping like i did ? or is there anything which will give me Unicode of selected drawable.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think that your code is the best way

Comment: okay.But making 844  entries manually is really donkey work

Comment: I know what you mean, but I don't think that there is a better way

Comment: @Rohan did you ever find a work around in this case?

Comment: @kabuto178 ..nope ..i continued same way as mentioned above